# Подгрузка CardView в фрагмент

Tags: java, android, adapter, cardview

Пытаюсь подгружать CardView в один из фрагментов. Но при открытии фрагмента приложение вылетает. В чем может быть проблема?

В логе ошибка:
`NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.example.gukov.guap.DirectionAdapter.getItemCount(DirectionAdapter.java:45)`

Код адаптера DirectionAdapter:
`public class DirectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context mCtx;
private List<Direction> directionList;

public DirectionAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Direction> DirectionList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.directionList = directionList;
}

@Override
public DirectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.direction, null);

    return new DirectionViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DirectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Direction direction = directionList.get(position);

    holder.textViewDirectionTitle.setText(direction.getDirectionTitle());
    holder.textViewDirectionCount.setText(direction.getDirectionCount());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return directionList.size();
}

class DirectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewDirectionTitle, textViewDirectionCount;

    public DirectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        textViewDirectionTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionTitle);
        textViewDirectionCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionCount);
    }

}}`
```

Код фрагмента SearchFragment:
`public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DirectionAdapter adapter;

List<Direction> directionList;

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), AddMeetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });


    directionList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext()));

    directionList.add(
            new Direction(
                    "Свидание",
                    "количество событий - 2"));

    directionList.add(
            new Direction(
                    "Кино",
                    "количество событий - 43"));

    DirectionAdapter adapter = new DirectionAdapter(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), directionList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}}`
```

Класс Direction:
`public class Direction {

```
private String directionTitle, directionCount;

public Direction(String directionTitle, String directionCount) {
    this.directionTitle = directionTitle;
    this.directionCount = directionCount;
}

public String getDirectionTitle() {
    return directionTitle;
}

public String getDirectionCount() {
    return directionCount;
}}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не следуете конвенциям именования переменных в `Java`. И не смотрите на подсказки IDE, которая говорит вам, что вы присваиваете одни переменные самим себе и не используете вовсе другие.

Если конкретно - у вас в конструкторе адаптера второй аргумент назван с большой буквы.